# Reactivating Camera2 in Android

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have a Camera2 based app that works just fine when you first go into the Activity. If you leave the Activity and go back though, it always crashes saying that the Camera has already been closed. I open the Camera initially in the surfaceChanged method of my SurfaceHolder.Callback. This never gets called outside of the initial load for some reason. I've looked and don't see anything I am doing in onCreate that I should refactor. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Here is a log of what I'm seeing:

```
I/CameraActivity: onResume
I/CameraActivity: VIDEO: Starting background thread
I/CameraActivity$onResume: VIDEO: Surface has changed.
I/CameraActivity: *** VIDEO: connectCamera deviceId: 0 ***
I/CameraActivity$deviceStateCallback: VIDEO: Camera device opened
I/CameraActivity$deviceStateCallback: VIDEO: On Device Callback Camera device ready for preview session
I/CameraActivity: VIDEO: onPause
I/CameraActivity: VIDEO: closeCamera
I/CameraActivity: VIDEO: Closing the camera
I/CameraActivity$deviceStateCallback: VIDEO: On Device Callback Camera device onClosed
I/CameraActivity: VIDEO: Stopping background thread
I/CameraActivity: onStop
I/CameraActivity: onResume
I/CameraActivity: VIDEO: Starting background thread
I/CameraActivity$onCreate: Turning camera ON
I/CameraActivity$onCreate: VIDEO: Setting previewSurfaceView's background color to transparent
I/CameraActivity$onCreate: Camera was not activated. Activating now
I/CameraActivity: Setting up Preview View mode
I/CameraActivity: VIDEO: Setting up preview session
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.stalkerradar, PID: 6547
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
    at  android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2228)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:789)
    at com.android.stalkerradar.ui.RadarEnabledActivity.previewSession(RadarEnabledActivity.kt:597)
    at com.android.stalkerradar.ui.RadarEnabledActivity.access$previewSession(RadarEnabledActivity.kt:51)
    at com.android.stalkerradar.ui.RadarEnabledActivity$onCreate$5.onClick(RadarEnabledActivity.kt:457)
```

Here is all of the relevant code.

```
         private lateinit var cameraDevice: CameraDevice
         private val deviceStateCallback = object: CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
               Timber.i("VIDEO: Camera device opened")
               camera.let{
                  Timber.i("VIDEO: On Device Callback Camera device ready for preview session")
                  cameraDevice = camera
               }
            }

            override fun onClosed(camera: CameraDevice) {
              super.onClosed(camera)
              Timber.i("VIDEO: On Device Callback Camera device onClosed")
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
              Timber.i("VIDEO: On Device Callback Camera device onDisconnected")
              camera.close()
            }

            override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
               Timber.w("VIDEO: On Device Callback Camera device onError: $error")
               finish()
            }
          }


        override fun onResume() {
           Timber.i("onResume")
           super.onResume()

           surfaceListener = object: SurfaceHolder.Callback {
               override fun surfaceCreated(p0: SurfaceHolder) { }

               override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                Timber.i("VIDEO: Surface has changed.")
                surfaceHolder = holder
                connectCamera()  //THIS IS WHERE THINGS NORMALLY GET SET UP FOR THE CAMERA
               }

               override fun surfaceDestroyed(p0: SurfaceHolder) { }
        }

        startBackgroundThread()

        previewSurfaceView.holder.setFixedSize(MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH, MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT)
        previewSurfaceView.holder.addCallback(surfaceListener)

     }

     override fun onPause() {
       super.onPause()
       Timber.i("VIDEO: onPause")
       closeCamera()
       stopBackgroundThread()
       previewSurfaceView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
       previewSurfaceView.holder.setFixedSize(0, 0)
       previewSurfaceView.holder.removeCallback(surfaceListener)
     }

      private fun previewSession() {
        Timber.i("VIDEO: Setting up preview session")
        val surface = surfaceHolder.surface

        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
          listOf(surface),
          object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){

            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
               Timber.w("VIDEO: creating capture session failed!")
            }

            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                Timber.i("VIDEO: Capture session created/configured")
                captureSession = session
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, 
                   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
                captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
              }
          },
          backgroundHandler)
      videoRecorderMasterFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.grey_400, null))
    }


      private fun closeCamera() {
        Timber.i("VIDEO: closeCamera")

        if (::captureSession.isInitialized) {
            Timber.i("VIDEO: Closing the capture session")
           captureSession.close()
        }

        if (::cameraDevice.isInitialized) {
            Timber.i("VIDEO: Closing the camera")
            cameraDevice.close()
        }
```

Comment: What are you doing in closeCamera()?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed it.

```
override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()

   startBackgroundThread()

   previewSurfaceView.holder.setFixedSize(MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH, MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT)
   previewSurfaceView.holder.addCallback(surfaceListener)
}

private fun stopCamera() {
   previewSurfaceView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}

override fun onPause() {
   super.onPause()
   closeCamera()
   stopBackgroundThread()
   previewSurfaceView.holder.setFixedSize(0, 0)
   previewSurfaceView.holder.removeCallback(surfaceListener)
}

private fun closeCamera() {
   if (::captureSession.isInitialized) {
       captureSession.close()
   }

   if (::cameraDevice.isInitialized) {
       cameraDevice.close()
   }
}
```